# Redirect to new URL safely using PHP

Tags: php

I've got a contact form that currently reloads the root page after sending an email.

`header('location: /?message=success');`

This works just fine, although I'd now like it to go to the page URL stored in `$_POST['contact_page']`. However, using something like the following code doesn't seem like good practice:

`header('location: http://'.$_POST['contact_page'].'?message=success');`

My main concern is that someone could change the URL to something nefarious and then this command would execute it. (Also, with the `message` argument in the new URL, repeatedly running this code will cause more and more instances of the same argument to be added to the end.)

My question: what's a safe way to redirect the user to `$_POST['contact_page']` using `header` (with an argument or two included, like `message` above)?

EDIT:
The page variable was originally made using this code, `$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]`, and ends up in the form www.mysite.com/whatever-page&maybe_some=leftover_arguments

Comment: How many possible endpoints could your application redirect to? Thousands, or just a few? Dynamic or fixed? You should use a whitelist of values considered acceptable to avoid open-redirect vulnerabilities.

Comment: Hmm, it's a contact form on a blog, so the visitor could be firing off the form from a growing number of articles…

Comment: So the contact form appears on many different posts, and is expected to redirect back to the same original post?

Comment: Yup, so if the visitor is on www.mysite.com/a-blog-about-fireworks and sends off a message from the footer's contact form, then she'll see the exact same page when it reloads (the contact form will then either say 'success' or 'invalid email', etc.).

Comment: And all of the posts are something to the effect of `a-blog-about-fireworks`? If so, you can validate the input with `preg_match()` to ensure it at least isn't an external URL, and redirect. Even if it doesn't point to a valid post, then the worst damage would be a 404.

Comment: Since you're using POST rather than GET its not like someone else can create a link that looks like it goes to your site but actually redirects someone to a different site. The user themselves would be the one putting a different url there, so does it actually harm anything?

Comment: Good idea! All the pages will be www.mysite.com/something with the potential for some trailing arguments. It looks like `preg_match()` will get me 50% there. The only problem is if there are trailing GET arguments in the URL. Perhaps I can find a way to easily strip these, and then problem solved.

Comment: @developerwjk I'm not sure—my concerns could definitely be misplaced. I don't know PHP thoroughly enough to say that there's not some bit of code that could be inserted that could do damage to the database or site. (e.g., https://xkcd.com/327/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because these links could either go to posts or pages—anything in the website's domain—and the list of allowable links will always be growing, I've gone with the following approach. It makes sure that the only arguments included in the redirect are of the form "page_id" and trims off anything else.

```
$page_url=$_POST['contact_page'];     // The URL to redirect to
$url_root=strtok($page_url,"?");    // Everything before the PHP arguments
$url_arg1=strtok("&")."&";          // The first argument
$ok_arg="page_id=";                 
if (strncmp($ok_arg,$url_arg1,strlen($ok_arg))!=0){ // Ditch first argument if not a page/post ID
    $url_arg1="";
}
header('location: http://'.$url_root.'?'.$url_arg1.'message=success');
```

Answer (score 2):

You must make a whitelist of what's allowed in your $_POST variable.

The previous answer by LuckyBurger can be incorrect if your PHP is <5.1.2 since it was allowed to send multiple headers with newline.

Comment: No manipulable in a link either way, since he's using $_POST not $_GET or $_REQUEST...

Comment: `HTTP_REFERER` is remarkably unreliable and is not supplied at all by some browsers **DO NOT** rely on it ever being a non-null value

Comment: You're true Martin. Corrected.

Answer (score 1):

```
header('location: /'.$_POST['contact_page'].'?message=success');
```

to

```
header('location: http://www.yourdomain.com/'.$_POST['contact_page'].'?message=success');
```

Comment: needs more explanation

Answer (score 1):

A better solution would be to just send the ID of your blog article in the form, and then translate that into a URL.  Don't actually use this code, it's more an illustration:

**HTML**

```
<form>
  <input type='hidden' name='blog_id' value='3'>
</form>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php

// do your form processing

$blogId = $_POST['blog_id'];

// query the database to get the blog post slug/URL
// (this is just an example, don't actually put POST vars directly into queries)
$query = "SELECT p.slug, p.url FROM my_blog_posts p WHERE p.id={$blogId}";
$result = executeMyQuery($query);

$postSlug = $result['slug'];
// OR
$postUrl = $result['url'];

header("location: http://www.yourdomain.com/{$postSlug}?message=success");
// OR
header("location: http://www.yourdomain.com/{$postUrl}");
```